# Scheduled Distribution is not working when excel is open

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, sap-epm

The issue is

if I schedule something from EPM and I let the excel be open with a blank workbook, when the task is triggered I don't see that it is opening the file.

Detailed explanation:

I have an option in epm from where I can distribute a workbook to users via mail or store in a particular folder.

A task will be scheduled in windows task scheduler, if I use that option.

So let's say I opened the excel and scheduled distribution for a workbook template, and I closed the excel.

Once it reaches the time, the task is getting triggered and distributed to the users via mail. (This is only when I closed the excel)

Let's say after i scheduled the distribution I stayed in the excel doing some other work, here the task is getting triggered again. I can see the windows command prompt. But it disappears right away without doing anything. No errors but it didn't do anything.

Usually it will say the publication has started and once the task is completed, it will the say the publication has completed. But it didn't happen.

I can see it is starting the excel application but not the workbook i believe.

But everything is working fine when the excel is closed.